# Import methods difference

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this import method:

```
import x
import y
```

different from this?

```
import x, y
```

Which import method should I prefer?

Comment: No.Does not really matter.

Comment: Whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [PEP8 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) you should use:

```
import x
import y
```

but in practical terms this does exactly the same as `import x, y`.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't different.

PEP-8 [recommends you import each separately](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) so I'd suggest you do that.

---

Yes:

```
import x
import y
```

No:

```
import x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to conform to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), then use one import by line.

Take a look at these examples:

**test1.py**

```
import json, csv
```

The following is the output of `pep8 test1.py`

```
>>> pep8 test1.py
test1.py:1:12: E401 multiple imports on one line
```

Now, with the following content, `pep8` does not complain!

**test2.py**

```
import json
import csv
```